# Algebraic numbers and their closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Are all of the roots/zeroes of a polynomial of finite degree with algebraic coefficients algebraic?

How about for a generalization of a polynomial wherein the indefinite is exponentiated to an algebraic power and then multiplied by an algebraic coefficient, where the number of terms is finite, provided that such a zero/root/value exists? In other words, must the values $z$ for which sums of summands of the form $az^b$, where $a$ and $b$ are algebraic, evaluate to zero be algebraic (if such $z$ exists)?

Comment: An irrational exponent kills the fun.

Comment: First question: yes. Second question: no. For example, $\sqrt2^{\sqrt2}$ is a root of $\frac1{\sqrt2}z^{\frac1{\sqrt2}}-1$, but it's not algebraic.

Comment: Thank you! How does one go about proving so, in general (or, really, even specifically)?

Comment: I found a sketch of a proof of the first question [here](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/361/lectures/lec09.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

I'll post my comments as an answer to reduce the number of unanswered questions.

The first question: Yes, all zeros to polynomials of finite degree with algebraic coefficients are algebraic, i.e. the field of algebraic numbers is algebraically closed. A proof sketch of this fact can be found [here](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/361/lectures/lec09.pdf).

A counter-example of the second question would be the equation $az^b-1=0$, where $a=b=\frac1{\sqrt2}$, which are algebraic, while its root $z=\sqrt2^{\sqrt2}$ is not.